# What is a "process object" in Windows?

Tags: windows, process, operating-system

I was reading Windows Internals, and I came across the term "process object" in Windows. This object is managed by the object manager, a component in the Windows Kernel.

So, I have some questions with regards to this:

1. I understand that each Windows process is represented by a EPROCESS block and 
   a PEB block. So, how does this "process object" relate to EPROCESS and PEB?
2. What exactly is this "process object"? Where is it located and what is it used for?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the Microsoft documentation for ['Windows kernel opaque structures'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/eprocess), the EPROCESS structure is an opaque structure that serves as the process object for a process. In other words, the EPROCESS structure is identical to the process object. 
You can use functions like PsGetCurrentProcess or NtOpenProcess to get a pointer to it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The EPROCESS or project object is located inside the Process Manager of the kernel right?

Comment: @Kyoma, the Process object is a data structure in the kernel address space. It's allocated by the process manager, not "inside" it. It's preceded by an object header, which has the handle count, object flags (e.g. permanent), security descriptor, and the index for the type object (i.e. "\ObjectTypes\Process"). The type object has statistics and info such as the type flags (e.g. security required), generic mapping, valid access mask, and type procedures (dump, open, close, delete, parse, security, query name, okay-to-close), if implemented, such as `PspProcessOpen`.

Comment: @Kyoma, you also asked about the PEB (Process Environment Block).  The `EPROCESS` structure contains a `Peb` pointer to the user-mode PEB, which is valid when attached to the process address space. This is information that's made easily accessible to user-mode functions (typically in ntdll.dll and kernelbase.dll) without requiring a system call. For example, the PEB contains a pointer to the `ProcessParameters`, which, among other things, has the command line, standard handles, and a pointer to the environment strings.